# How to extract residual sum of squares from C LAPACKE_sgelss with LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR

Tags: lapack, intel-mkl, lapacke

I am using MKL LAPACKE_sgelss to compute least square solution to $Ax = b_j$, where $j \in [0 , nrhs) $, A is $m \times n$ matrix and $n < m < nrhs$.

I somehow managed to extract the solution and even the singular values of A. What I do not know is how to extract residual sum of squares. There is cryptic sentence in the [documentation](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-0/gelss.html):

*If m≥n and rank = n, the residual sum-of-squares for the solution in the i-th column is given by the sum of squares of modulus of elements n+1:m in that column.*

My code does not seem to extract them properly. To be honest, I don't understand very well what is the meaning of the word "modulus". And why they speak about the column when in the row major order it would make more sense to be stored in the row.

The following pseudocode seems to work:

```
    int m = 100;
    int n = 10;
    int nrhs = 1000;
    float* A = new float[m * n]();
    float* b = new float[m * nrhs](); // Prealocated with zeros
    float* results = new float[n * nrhs]();
    uint32_t i = 0;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i != m; i++)
    {
        //Fill A to write corresponding row into the address [A + i * n, A + i*n + n)
        //Fill b to write corresponding row into the address [b + i * nrhs, b + i*nrhs + nrhs)
        //in this row are the values of i-th element of each b_j vector in order
    }
    int inf;
    std::string err;
    float* s = new float[n];
    float rcond = 1e-6; //  1e-9 too small, 1e-5 causing problems maybe to big
    lapack_int rank;
    inf = LAPACKE_sgelss(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, m, n, nrhs, A, n, b, nrhs, s, rcond, &rank);
    if(s[1] < 1e-7)
    {
        LOGE << io::xprintf("Highly rank deficient matrix!");
    }
    if(rank < n)
    {
        LOGE << io::xprintf("Rank deficient matrix!");
    }
    std::string msg
        = io::xprintf("Reported numerical rank of A is %d, singular values %f", rank, s[0]);
    for(uint32_t I = 1; I < n; I++)
    {
        msg = io::xprintf("%s, %f", msg.c_str(), s[I]);
    }
    LOGI << io::xprintf("%s.", msg.c_str());
    delete[] s;
    for(uint32_t i = 0;  i != n; i++)
    {
         std::copy(b + i *nrhs, b+ (i+1)*nrhs, results+i*nrhs);
    }
    //results array [results+i*nrhs, results+i*nrhs+nrhs) shall now contain i-th element of solution x for all right hand sides
    float* rss = new float[nrhs];
    std::fill(rss, rss + nrhs, 0.0f);
    double modulus, sum;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i != nrhs; i++)
    {
        sum = 0.0;
        for(uint32_t j = n; j != m; j++)
        {
            modulus = b[j * nrhs + i];
            sum += modulus*modulus;
        }
        rss[i] = std::sqrt(sum);
    }
```

Can you help me to understand how these j-th moduli are actually computed?

Comment: sum += modulus * modulus; provides correct result. How these moduli are computed seems to be tricky as they need to support this operation.

Comment: It seems that residual error from the rows, which gets overwritten by solution are distributed over the whole rest of the vector. I still don't know how and what is exact meaning of that modulus.